# multiprocessing - shared counter shows negative value

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement multiprocessing counter in my script, but not sure if I'm doing things right, since results does not making any sense.

```
# Global shared variable 
total_bytes_written = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)

# Worker method
def s3_put_worker(**kwargs):
    global total_bytes_written
    # local var that stores a data chunk length
    data_chunk_len = len(data_chunk)

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        # do some work
        # ...
        # The counter that sums shared_total_written variable with local var
        with total_bytes_written.get_lock():
            total_bytes_written.value += data_chunk_len

# I'm using ProcessPoolExecutor to start several Gevent thread pools that runs my worker method
```

Now after stopping the script I've got those weird results:

```
2018-11-06 04:42:55,412; [s3_stress.s3_stress_runner] (MainProcess : MainThread) INFO - Total bytes written to storage: -1946157056
```

I suspect that I can't sum multiprocessing shared var with local method's var, but I can't find anything about this topic, and how to workaround the issue.

Thanks

Comment: You are using a fixed byte signed integer. It likely overflowed.

Comment: Oh :). @MisterMiyagi maybe. But I was pretty sure that int32 (2147483647) is big enough to contain my counter

Comment: ``int32`` is enough to count about 2 GiB, and an overflow to ``-1946157056`` would require about 2.2 GiB. I do not know what data you are handling, but it seems more likely than Python semantics stopping to work in a common situation. ;)

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi, do you know if python's shared variables supports number bigger than 1PB (petabyte), which is 1,125,899,906,842,580.00 in bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your problem is from overflow: `Value('i', 0)` is a signed 32 bit integer, which can count up to 2147483647 (roughly 2GiB for byte counting).

```
>>> total_bytes_written = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
>>> total_bytes_written.value += 2147483647  # 2GiB - 1B
>>> total_bytes_written
<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(2147483647)>
>>> total_bytes_written.value += 1
>>> total_bytes_written
<Synchronized wrapper for c_int(-2147483648)>
```

The largest [data type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) for `Value` is `'Q'` for unsigned long long (at least 64bit). This can handle the range `[0, 18_446_744_073_709_551_615]` or up to 16EiB for byte counting. If you care about proper sign handling, the signed long long type `'q'` can still count up to 8EiB.

```
>>> total_bytes_written = multiprocessing.Value('q', 0)
>>> total_bytes_written.value += 9223372036854775807  # 8EiB - 1B
>>> total_bytes_written
<Synchronized wrapper for c_long(9223372036854775807)>
```